# babel command converts when run in terminal but running the script ends in error

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, babeljs, babel-loader

I've been trying to get babel core and cli to convert modern JavaScript from index.js into bundle.js.

here is my simple package.json

```
{
    "name": "chapter19",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "babel": "./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/index.js -w -o ./dist/assets/bundle.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.16.7",
        "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.7",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.3"
    }
}
```

now when I run `node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/index.js -w -o ./dist/assets/bundle.js` in terminal, it works fine but when I try to run "npm run babel" in terminal, I get the following errors. so far here is what I've tried :

```
"babel": "node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -w -o dist/assets/bundle.js"
```

result: 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
"babel": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -w -o dist/assets/bundle.js"
```

result:'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823855/node-modules-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) issue, which is basically:

```
"babel": "node ./node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -w -o dist/assets/bundle.js"
```

OR

```
"babel": "node ./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src/index.js -w -o ./dist/assets/bundle.js"
```

and I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

here is my folder structure (in case if its needed)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested in resolving this issue, in Windows you can use the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "babel": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\babel src\\index.js -w -o dist\\assets\\bundle.js"
},
```