# 'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

`PS E:\Web\Javascript course\Babel Practice> npm run babel

```
> weather_app@1.0.0 babel
> node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -o dist/assets/bundle.js

'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

// I'm using this script
"scripts": {
    "babel": "node_modules/.bin/babel src/index.js -o dist/assets/bundle.js"
}

// Even if I add './' in start, it does not work
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`
```

Comment: Duplicate of [node\_modules is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823855/node-modules-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute this command before :`run npm install` it will install the necessary dependencies to run the command you want to run

Comment: Yes, I have done npm install a lot of times, and I have the dependencies.
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4"
  }

Comment: you need to provide relative path properly:

"scripts": {
    "test": "node ./node_modules/webdriverio/bin/wdio wdio.conf.js",
    "start": "wdio wdio.conf.js"
  }