# Webpack.js Module not Found - React & Django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, webpack

> frontend@1.0.0 build
> webpack --mode production

'React\music_controller\frontend\node_modules.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw err;
^

I am just starting out with react and Django and I'm having this error when I run the command 'npm run dev' .

There are my scripts from my package.json file if this helps:
"scripts": {
"dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
"build": "webpack --mode production"
},

I am just starting out with react and Django and I'm having this error when I run the command 'npm run dev' .

There are my scripts from my package.json file if this helps:
"scripts": {
"dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
"build": "webpack --mode production"
},

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823855/node-modules-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command